# Phrasing SQL that has subquery returning multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am tring to query a set of data from mySQL with the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE datediff((now()), (SELECT datepurchased FROM orders WHERE email = 'me@example.com')) <= 1
```

But the problem is I get the error that `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row` because the statement `SELECT datepurchased FROM orders WHERE email = 'me@example.com'` is returning more than one rows, which is perfectly correct.

The idea that I wanted is to select from the `orders` table such that the date difference between the current time and the `datepurchased` field is `<=1` and that the `email` field is equals to `me@example.com`.

There could be many rows in the `orders` table with their email fields as `me@example.com`. I just want to find out all of these rows with `email` fields equals `me@example.com` that have `datepurchased` less than or equals one.

How should I phrase my SQL to achieve this?

Comment: Someone please tell me why Don Kirkby's answer is being down voted when it is the exact same as the other 4 current answers and they are being voted up?

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli - Probably but just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. I dislike the whole down vote with no reason thing, it turns a chance for constructive criticism into near-uselessness. Completely counter productive for a site that is supposed to be about learning and problem solving..... not necessarily in that order.

Comment: @Bryan: You're preaching to the choir. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for a subquery in this case. Simply:

```
SELECT *
    FROM orders
    WHERE email = 'me@example.com'
        AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), datepurchased) <= 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a subquery, just put two where conditions on your `orders` query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   orders 
WHERE  datediff(now(), datepurchased) <= 1
AND    email = 'me@example.com'
```

I haven't tried it, but it seems simple enough.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want an ordinary SELECT with a WHERE clause containing two conditions:

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE email = 'me@example.com')
AND datediff(now(), datepurchased) <= 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I'm missing something, but why wouldn't you be able to do this?

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE datediff(now(), datepurchased ) <= 1
and email = 'me@example.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
SELECT * 
    FROM orders
    WHERE datediff(now(), datepurchased) <= 1
      AND email = 'me@example.com'
```

?